# Is there any way to auto refresh some content every X seconds in AMP Pages?

Tags: html, refresh, amp-html

Is there any way to have a refresh "function" on AMP pages to repeat a task every X seconds?

I need to call and API url every X seconds and with the response, modify part of page content.

In javascript I was doing it with setTimeout, but I could not find anything that would do it in AMP.

I've checked [amp-bind refresh state](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-bind/), but it seems that it only works for tapping interactions.

```html
<div>
    <amp-state id="time"
      src="/components/time"></amp-state>
    <button on="tap:time.refresh">
      Refresh
    </button>
    <div [text]="time"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please take into account the AMP cache. If you expect the frequent data updates then you will need to flush the AMP cache too, otherwise Google will serve the cached content, see more details [here](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache)

Comment: Thank you Kate, gonna consider this point also

Comment: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-live-list/ perhaps?